# Excel formula: use cell content as path

Tags: excel, formula

I want to evaluate a table with data in another excel file. The file is saved in the column `[@Spektrum]`

Without it looks like this (... is the removed company path)

```
=IF([@Spektrum]<>"";MAX('\\...\Lichtquellen\LED\Spektren\630\[Ledengin LZ1-00R102 (625nm).xlsx]1309136U1_01'!$B$7:$B$1317);"")
```

with

```
[@Spektrum] = Spektren\630\Ledengin LZ1-00R102 (625nm).xlsx
```

I tried this

```
=IF([@Spektrum]<>"";MAX("'\\...\Lichtquellen\LED\" & [@Spektrum] &"1309136U1_01'!$B$7:$B$1317);"")
```

Excel does not except the formula. It changes it to

```
=IF([@Spektrum]<>"";MAX('\\...\Lichtquellen\LED\[" & [@Spektrum] &"1309136U1_01]" & [@Spektrum] &"1309136U1_01'!$B$7:$B$1317);"")
```

which results in `#REF!`

I would like to know how to fix this.

Comment: There is a duplicated `]` in your `MAX` part. And put a `"` at the end of `$B$1317`

Comment: The `]` was wrong, the `"` not. However this did not solve it.

Comment: Use an `INDIRECT` formula. `INDIRECT("\\...\Lichtqueelen....."&[@Spektrum]&"130913........$B$1317")`